# Qt - 4.7.3 - How to make static build

Tags: c++, windows, qt, logic

I used 4.7.2 for the past months. Now I downloaded 4.7.3. Now I am searching to type "configure -static". But I don't know where the hell "the qt path". Can anybody shed a light on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download the source package [here](ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3.zip). Download and install your favorite perl distribution. I must warn you that Strawberry perl comes with its own toolchain and that may get used instead of the MinGW you downloaded. Use ActivePerl if you don't want any trouble, or build it yourself.
2. Unzip it to say, `C:\Qt-source` so that there is a `configure.exe` in `C:\Qt-source`
3. Open the toolchain's command prompt

   a) If you're using the Visual Studio compiler, search in the "start" menu for a CMD shortcut in the Visual Studio folder. The Windows SDK also has this shortcut.

   b) If you're using MinGW, either use the accompanying `mingwvars.cmd`, or open a command prompt, (Run->"cmd.exe") and type `set PATH=C:\path\to\mingw\bin;%PATH%`. Try `gcc -v` to see if it can be found.
4. Make a build directory, preferable something like `C:\Qt`. Do `set QTPATH=C:\Qt` and `set PATH=C:\Qt\bin;%PATH%` and `cd C:\Qt`, and type:

   ..\Qt-source\configure -static
5. After configure finishes, you'll either have to type `nmake` (Visual Studio) or `mingw32-make`.
6. Go do something else, because it will take a while.

Comment: I found a web- windows installer in qt.nokia.*** - downloads. I downloaded that web installer. It downloaded 1.5GB windows package. Now I installed it. Is there any possible way to make the static build out of it.

Comment: Not that I know. I don't think it comes with all the source code, but you could try, if there is a `configure.exe` in the install directory

Comment: @prabhakaran: Download the Qt source, not the SDK (which is for mobile development).

Comment: 1b: Download perl. The build process *still* doesn't check for that; instead there's a silent error: `%QtPath%\src\corelib\global\qglobal.h(62) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/qconfig.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: @MSalters: I guess it still doesn't. Stupid. I added some details about perl for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips that result from my experience, and add a bit more to the answer of rubenv:

- Pass the install directory as a flag of the configure; be sure to choose a different directory from the one where you have stored a non-static version of Qt!
- Some modules will likely cause you troubles when compiling statically because you need to resolve the dependencies statically; one example is webkit, so if you don't need it be sure to disable it
- It is generally not a good idea to build the debug symbols into a static library, so I normally debug with the dynamic version, and use the static Qt to generate releases only.

Therefore, my configure looks something like this:

```
configure -static -prefix C:\Qt\4.8.6_static -no-webkit -release
```