# Building Qt 4.7.3 (latest) on windows

Tags: qt

I have downloaded the open source version of Qt 4.7.3, run configure.exe to configure it, how do I then build it (to have a qmake.exe I can use) on windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt - 4.7.3 - How to make static build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167820/qt-4-7-3-how-to-make-static-build) I understand it's not a complete duplicate, but my answer to that question is as clear as it can get. Just forget the `-static` part.

Answer (score 1):

if you do `configure -platform win32-msvc2010` (or2008 etc) it will generate a vs2010 project, just open the .sln and built it.

Answer (score 1):

configure.exe should have caused qmake.exe to build. You'll want to add its location to your path. (It's in the bin directory of your Qt installation).

Comment: Thanks, this is an important step.

Comment: At the risk of not following etiquette, may I ask for a vote up then?