# Trying to build static Qt project, cannot find configure.exe

Tags: windows, qt

I'm trying to follow the advice in this question:

[Building Qt 4.7.3 (latest) on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496500/building-qt-4-7-3-latest-on-windows)

It talks about where configure.exe is. In my installation, which includes 4.7.4 and 4.8.1 for Windows, I only find configure.exe in Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt474/

Is this the right executable, and should I be adding that Symbian directory to my %PATH% so the Visual Studio command prompt can find it?

This just doesn't seem to be in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have downloaded the [Qt libraries](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#qt-lib) and not the SDK. The SDK is a binary distribution, the source code in it is generally only for reference purposes.

Comment: Ok, I got the SDK. If I DL this libraries package, do I just install it, or since I already have the SDK are there some special things I need to do?

Comment: That depends on many things :) Generally I would say no but if you encounter any problems, come back with a new question.