# Building Qt statically

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Qt - 4.7.3 - How to make static build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167820/qt-4-7-3-how-to-make-static-build)

I have read tutorial after tutorial and have given up trying to build Qt statically (to make a standalone .exe on windows with no dlls etc). Is there a pre-compiled static version of Qt 4.7.3 in a zip someone can link to this question (I think it would be useful to others) for Qt creator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no redistributable installer for Qt aside from the official one. A Qt build is a pain to relocate, so no-one bothers to jump through the hoops, and just build it themselves.