# Build QT statically ver 5.0.2

Tags: qt

I am trying to build the QT static version by using the information from this link [Qt - 4.7.3 - How to make static build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167820/qt-4-7-3-how-to-make-static-build). But i am using 5.0.2 as i have developed some applications using the same.

I am using windows 64 bit + MINGW32 and active-perl.

**First-fix:**
I had to comment the line number 45(if not exist %QTSRC%.gitignore goto sconf) in the file qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2\qtbase\configure.bat

My configuration command looks like this `..\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2\configure -platform win32-g++ -static -release -no-opengl` . This executed well without any errors.

**Problem:**
Now i run `mingw32-make`. And i get an error which says

/usr/bin/sh: c:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe: Invalid argument
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-tools-make_first] Error 126

I have pasted the entire error log below. Could any body please kindly point me the cause of this error or the solution.

**Entire error log**

```
C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2\qt>mingw32-make
cd qtbase/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase/bin/qmake C:/Qt/qt-everywhere-ope
nsource-src-5.0.2/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase/qtbase.pro -o Makefile ) && mingw32-make -f Makefile
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `c:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase'
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase/bin/qmake C:/Qt/qt-everywhere-openso
urce-src-5.0.2/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && d:/tools/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/bin/mingw
32-make -f Makefile
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `c:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase/src'
cd tools/ && ( test -e Makefile || c:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe C:/Qt/qt-everywhere-
opensource-src-5.0.2/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtbase/src/tools/tools.pro -o Makefile ) && d:/tools/Dev-Cpp/Min
GW32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile
/usr/bin/sh: c:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe: Invalid argument
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-tools-make_first] Error 126
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `c:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase/src'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `c:/Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qt/qtbase'
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Static builds are supported [from Qt 5.1](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.1), not 5.0. You might want to upgrade ;-)